# Bootstrap 4.5.0 responsive grid failing

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Following a Django tutorial I've come to bootstrap cards, with css styling. I used the latest version (bootstrap 4.5.0) and my grid is responsive (increasing the screen size, the cards move accordingly), but they are overlapping each other. Then I saw that on the tutorial, the bootstrap version being used was 4.1, and changing the href on the base.html file made it work (with the exact same code for index.html).

Then I opened both versions on the browser and found that deactivating the **min-width: 0** for the **class="col"** solved the error on the 4.5.0 version of the link. I download the 4.5 css, added to the project files, removed the min-width style and it worked beautifully.

The question is: Am I using it wrong in the index.html or it's some kind of bug? (problem occurred both on Opera 68.0.3618.125 and Chrome 83.0.4103.97)

The version that works as it is: https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css

index.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Products</h1>
<div class="row">
    {% for product in products %}
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ product.image_url }}" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.name }}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">${{ product.price }}</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
<html lang="en">
     <head>
     <!-- Required meta tags -->
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

     <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384- 
      9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container">
         {% block content %}
         {% endblock %}
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't with `.col` but rather the inline style that you are applying to each `.card` component. The way `.col` works without a modifier (ex. `.col-sm-2`) is to attempt to fit everything into the width of a single `.row` regardless of how many columns you have specified.

By applying an inline width to each `.card` you are overriding the width of each `.col`.

The solution is fairly straightforward: Utilize Bootstrap's built in column modifiers and eliminate your inline style.  An example of that structure follows:

```
<div class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
  <div class="card">
   <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ product.image_url }}" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
     <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.name }}</h5>
     <p class="card-text">${{ product.price }}</p>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

In the above example Bootstrap's grid would function as follows:

- At the lowest breakpoint, each column would span half the width of the container.
- At the `SM` breakpoint, each column would span a third of the container.
- AT the `MD` breakpoint and above, each column would span a fourth of the container.